# animating scrollTop with jQuery always starts from the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to programm animating scrollTop to places on current page.
I have a fixed menu with some links on the left and content with some divs on the right.
Clicking on links on menu should animate to specific div.

```
var boxes = $('#container .box');
var boxesLength = boxes.length;
var offsets = [];

for(var i = 0; i < boxesLength; i++) {
    offsets.push($('#praca_container .box:eq('+ i +')').offset().top);
} 

$('a').click(function() {
  var index = $('a').index(this);
  $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: offsets[index] - 50});
}
```

It's animating to correct places but always from top to specific places. Why is that animating always from top and could You help me to create effect of animating from place to place without starting from top?

I also tried to calculate distance and animating scrollTop with '+=' but the same effect as i mentioned before was received.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? im having the same issue =(

Comment: make sure the function calling jQuery animate isn't being called twice at the same time. I had an issue where the same function was being called twice and the first time was resetting the scrollTop back to 0 which caused the div to jump on animation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click handler you need to suppress the default behavior, which apparently includes scrolling to the top of the window:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var index = $('a').index(this);
  $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: offsets[index] - 50});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of offset().top use element.scrollTop, you want to the scroll position of the element, not the top position of the element which is where it is on the screen only (as it could be scrolled down already)..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

```
var boxes = $('#container .box');
var boxesLength = boxes.length;
var offsets = [];

for(var i = 0; i < boxesLength; i++) {
    offsets.push($('#praca_container .box:eq('+ i +')').scrollTop()); //notice the change
} 

$('a').click(function() {
  var index = $('a').index(this);
  $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: offsets[index] - 50});
}
```

Comment: if I change to scrollTop(), the offsets array is filled only with zeros. `If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow or if the element is non-scrollable), scrollTop is set to 0.`[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollTop)